# A theorem about whether or not the topology on $X$ is the initial topology induced by some family of maps on $X$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I'm reading about initial topology from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology#Separating_points_from_closed_sets) Wikipedia page.

---

#### Separating points from closed sets

If a space $X$ comes equipped with a topology, it is often useful to know whether or not the topology on $X$ is the initial topology induced by some family of maps on $X$. This section gives a sufficient (but not necessary) condition.

A family of maps $\left\{f_i: X \rightarrow Y_i\right\}$ separates points from closed sets in $X$ if for all closed sets $A$ in $X$ and all $x$ not in $A$, there exists some $i$ such that
$$
f_i(x) \notin \operatorname{cl}\left(f_i(A)\right)
$$
where $\mathrm{cl}$ denotes the closure operator.

> **Theorem** A family of continuous maps $\left\{f_i: X \rightarrow Y_i\right\}$ separates points from closed sets if and only if the cylinder sets $f_i^{-1}(U)$, for $U$ open in $Y_{\mathrm{i}}$, form a base for the topology on $X$.

It follows that whenever $\left\{f_i\right\}$ separates points from closed sets, the space $X$ has the initial topology induced by the maps $\left\{f_i\right\}$. The converse fails, since generally the cylinder sets will only form a subbase (and not a base) for the initial topology.

---

Could you elaborate on if there are references that contain the proof of above theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know a reference, but here is a proof.

1. Let $\{f_i: X \rightarrow Y_i\}$ separate points from closed sets. We have to show that each open $V \subset X$ and each $x \in V$ there exist $i$ and an open $U \subset Y_i$ such that $x \in f_i^{-1}(U) \subset V$.
   The set $A =  X \setminus V$ is closed and $x \notin A$. There exists $i$ such  that $f_i(x) \notin \operatorname{cl}(f_i(A))$. Let $U = Y_i  \setminus \operatorname{cl}(f_i(A))$. Then $f_i(x) \in U$, thus $x \in f_i^{-1}(U)$. Consider $x' \in  f_i^{-1}(U)$. Then $f_i(x') \in U$, thus $f_i(x') \notin \operatorname{cl}(f_i(A))$ and all the more $f_i(x') \notin f_i(A)$. Hence $x' \notin A$. This proves $x' \in V$.
2. Let the $f_i^{-1}(U)$ form a base for the topology on $X$. We have to show that for each closed $A \subset X$ and each $x \notin A$ there exist $i$ such that $f_i(x) \notin \operatorname{cl}(f_i(A))$.
   The set $V = X \setminus A$ is open and $x \in V$. There exist $i$ and an open $U \subset Y_i$ such that $x \in f_i^{-1}(U) \subset V$. In particular $f_i(x) \in U$. Now assume that $f_i(x) \in \operatorname{cl}(f_i(A))$. Then $U \cap f_i(A) \ne \emptyset$. This means that there exists $a \in A$ such that $f_i(a) \in U$, thus $a \in f_i^{-1}(U) \subset V$ which is a contradiction because $A \cap V = \emptyset$.

Comment: I posted my proof as an answer below. Could you have a check on it?

Comment: @Analyst It is correct!

Answer (score 1):

1. Assume the family $\{f_i: X \to Y_i \}_{i\in I}$ of continuous maps separates points from closed subsets of $X$.

Let $O$ be an open subset of $X$ and $x \in O$. Then $x \notin A :=O^c$. There is $i\in I$ such that $f_i (x) \notin F:= \overline{f_i(A)}$. Clearly, $F$ is closed and
$$
x \in U := (f_i^{-1}(F))^c = f_i^{-1}(F^c).
$$

Because $f_i$ is continuous, $U$ is open. Let's prove that $U \subset O$ or equivalently $A \subset U^c$. Indeed,
$$
U^c = f_i^{-1}(F) \supset f_i^{-1} (f_i(A)) \supset A.
$$

2. Assume the cylinder sets $f_i^{-1}(U)$, for $U$ open in $Y_{i}$, form a base for the topology on $X$.

Let $A$ be a closed subset of $X$ and $x \notin A$. Then $x \in A^c$. There is $i\in I$ and $U$ open in $Y_i$ such that
$$
x \in O := f_i^{-1} (U) \subset A^c.
$$

We have $A \subset (f_i^{-1} (U))^c = f_i^{-1} (U^c)$. Hence $f_i(A) \subset f_i(f_i^{-1} (U^c)) \subset U^c$ and thus $\overline{f_i(A)} \subset U^c$. So $f_i(x) \in f_i (O) = f_i (f_i^{-1} (U)) \subset U$ and thus $f_i (x) \notin \overline{f_i(A)}$.